# Как в реальном времени получить фидбэк от хранимой процедуры?

Tags: oracle, plsql, процедуры

На основе представления обновляю и вставляю миллионы строк в других таблицах посредством хранимой процедуры. Выполняется очень долго до нескольких часов.
Поэтому хотелось бы получать какой-то фидбэк от хранимой процедуры. C `dbms_output.put_line` проблема в том, что вывод приходит только тогда, когда хранимая процедура завершает выполнение.

Есть ещё какие-нибудь варианты кроме `dbms_output.put_line`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Пусть процедура пишет лог своих действий (или только ошибок). Из таблицы-лога дергайте записи.
У нас почти все процедуры логи пишут, потом достаточно удобно отслеживать правильность действий.

Answer (score 6):

Чтобы получить фидбэк от процесса выполнения хранимой процедуры в реальном времени, необходимо обеспечить обмен данными между двумя сессиями. Одной, в которой хранимая процедура выполняется, и другой, в которой надо получить фидбэк.
Основным механизмом такого обмена является *db pipes*, который напомиминает *named pipes* в Unix и многие инструменты в БД *Oracle* используют его, например `dbms_alert`.
Низкоуровневый пакет для него `dbms_pipe`. Пример для реализации следует.

В первой сессии запустите блок, который ожидает фидбэк от "долгоиграющей" процедуры. Он как-бы подвиснет, ожидая этот фидбэк:

```
begin 
    declare msg notification; 
    begin <<receiveUntilEOF>> loop  
        msg := notification.receive;
        dbms_output.put_line (msg.print);
        exit receiveUntilEOF when msg.text = 'EOF';
    end loop receiveUntilEOF; end;
end;
/
```

Во второй сессии запустите "долгоиграющую" процедуру:

```
begin
    notification.send ('start');
    for i in 1..3 loop
        dbms_lock.sleep (3);
        notification.send ('part '||i||' finished');
    end loop;    
    notification.send ('EOF');
end;
/
```

В первой сессии выведет сообщения отправленные во второй сессии. Время отправки и приёма совпадают, т.е. асинхронный фидбэк в реальном времени:

```
received at 16:55:18 sent at 16:55:18: start
received at 16:55:21 sent at 16:55:21: part 1 finished
received at 16:55:24 sent at 16:55:24: part 2 finished
received at 16:55:27 sent at 16:55:27: part 3 finished
received at 16:55:27 sent at 16:55:27: EOF
```

Пользовательский тип, который необходимо предварительно создать для демонстрации примера:

```
create or replace type notification as object (
    dt date,
    text varchar2 (32676),
    static procedure send (text varchar2),
    static function receive return notification,
    member function print return varchar2
);
/
create or replace type body notification as
    static procedure send (text varchar2) is
        result  integer;
    begin
        dbms_pipe.pack_message(sysdate);
        dbms_pipe.pack_message(text);
        result := dbms_pipe.send_message('pipe$notification');
        if result != 0 then
            raise_application_error (-20001, 'notification pipe send error result='||result);
        end if;
    end;
    static function receive return notification is
        result integer;
        ret notification := notification (null, null);
    begin
        result := dbms_pipe.receive_message (pipename => 'pipe$notification');
        if result = 0 then
            dbms_pipe.unpack_message (ret.dt);
            dbms_pipe.unpack_message (ret.text);
        else
            raise_application_error (-20002, 'notification.receive errror result='||result);
        end if;
        return ret;
    end;
    member function print return varchar2 is
    begin 
        return 'received at '||to_char (sysdate, 'hh24:mi:ss')||' sent at '||to_char (dt, 'hh24:mi:ss')||': '||text;
    end;
end;
/
```

Comment: @Alexandr_TT Згораю от стыда за такие опечатки, спасибо.

Comment: Сгораю :-) не обращайте внимание и не принимайте близко к сердцу.  Ответы ваши так хороши, что кроме опечаток и не найдешь, что править. А насчет опечаток,- ведь мы люди, а не роботы и нам всем свойственно ошибаться. Думаете у меня меньше очепяток, отнюдь...

Answer (score 3):

Простой способ получить фидбэк из долго выполняющейся хранимой процедуры с помощью пакета `dbms_application_info`. Преимущество: простота реализации, а недостатки: не асинхронный опрос, только 64 байта информации, нет истории.

Надо добавить в процедуру информацию о выполнении:

```
dbms_application_info.set_module (
    module_name=>'myLongPlayOp', action_name=>'insert_multiple_Tables');

dbms_application_info.set_client_info(client_info=>'insert into table1 start');
-- insert into table1 ...    
dbms_application_info.set_client_info(client_info=>'insert into table1 done..table2 start');
-- insert into table2 ...    
dbms_application_info.set_client_info(client_info=>'insert into table2 done');
```

Опрашивать можно так, где `sid=135` идентификатор сессии, где выполняется хранимая процедура:

```
select sid, module||'.'||action||': '||client_info from v$session where sid=135;
```

В различный момент времени запрос вернёт последнее состояние процесса выполнения:

```
135 myLongPlayOp.insert_multiple_Tables: insert into table1 start
135 myLongPlayOp.insert_multiple_Tables: insert into table1 done..table2 start
135 myLongPlayOp.insert_multiple_Tables: insert into table2 done
```

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь функцией [DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_SESSION_LONGOPS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.html#GUID-A5E0BCFA-229C-4EA7-BDE7-E926A4ED530C), она разработана специально для отслеживания длительных операций.

Вот воспроизводимый пример, как она работает:

```
declare
    rindex pls_integer := dbms_application_info.set_session_longops_nohint;
    slno pls_integer;
    totalwork number := 100000;
    sofar number := 0;
begin
    while sofar < totalwork loop
        -- Do some work
        dbms_session.sleep(1);
        sofar := sofar + 1000;
        dbms_application_info.set_session_longops (
            rindex=>rindex, slno=>slno, op_name=> 'Batch load stage', 
            sofar=>sofar, totalwork=>totalwork, units=>'rows processed',
            target_desc=>'EXT_STAGE_TABLE');
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Прогресс выполнения можно наблюдать с [V$SESSION_LONGOPS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/V-SESSION_LONGOPS.html#GUID-F2802C36-066C-493E-8255-C08CC79B87FB) в другой сессии:

```
select start_time, opname, target_desc, sofar, totalwork, units
from v$session_longops
where opname = 'Batch load stage' 
/

START_TIME          OPNAME           TARGET_DESC           SOFAR  TOTALWORK UNITS
------------------- ---------------- ---------------- ---------- ---------- --------------
2020-08-25 17:36:17 Batch load stage EXT_STAGE_TABLE       96000     100000 rows processed

/** или */
select message
from v$session_longops
where opname = 'Batch load stage' 
/

MESSAGE
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Batch load stage: EXT_STAGE_TABLE : 60000 out of 100000 rows processed done
```

---

Кроме того, многие инструменты поддерживают *LONGOPS*, например, в SQL Developer *Monitor Sessions* можно будет наблюдать прогресс выполнения активного модуля:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а разве долго выполняющиеся операции сами по себе не попадают в `V$SESSION_LONGOPS`?

Comment: @MaxU В PL/SQL автоматом нет. В SQL вроде после 6 сек.

Comment: спасибо за информацию! не подскажете ссылку на то, где об этом в документации написано?

Comment: @MaxU Конечно, по второй ссылке первое предложение.

Comment: если я правильно помню, то "долгоиграющие" операции, запущенные из PL/SQL тоже должны появляться в `V$SESSION_LONGOPS`, но я могу ошибаться...

Comment: @MaxU Тоже могу ошибиться, но последние самописные не появлялись. Может не так смотрел? Сейчас перед походом в магаз запущу пустышку на пол-часа, посмотрим.

Comment: @MaxU Не, пусто. То есть, если нет внутренних оракловых модулей или долгих запросов, то для самого PL/SQL блока в .v$session_longops не будет записей.

Comment: Да, это логично. Спасибо за проверку! :)

Answer (score 1):

dbms_pipe  - быстро и с минимальными затратами.

Comment: С минимальными затратами чего? Ресурсов, времени?

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно с `dbms_alert`.

Запустить приемник:

```
 DECLARE
     message VARCHAR2(1800) := 'NONE';
     status NUMBER := -1;
 BEGIN
     dbms_alert.register('status$_queue');
     <<reading>> LOOP
         dbms_alert.waitone('status$_queue', message, status);
         dbms_output.put_line(sysdate||': received status '||status||' message '||message);
         IF status != 0 OR message = 'END_OF_TX' THEN
             EXIT reading;
         END IF;
     END LOOP reading;
     dbms_alert.remove('status$_queue');
 END;
 /
```

В другом окне запустить эмулятор процедуры:

```
 DECLARE
     PROCEDURE signal (message VARCHAR2) is
     PRAGMA autonomous_transaction;
     BEGIN
         dbms_alert.signal ('status$_queue', message);
         COMMIT;
     END;
 BEGIN
     signal('START');
     dbms_lock.sleep(1);
     signal('got chunk #1 done');
     dbms_lock.sleep(1);
     signal('got chunk #2 done');
     signal('END_OF_TX');
 END;
 /
```

Вывод в приемнике:

```
2018-03-26  19:56:28: received status 0 message START
2018-03-26  19:56:29: received status 0 message got chunk #1 done
2018-03-26  19:56:30: received status 0 message got chunk #2 done
2018-03-26  19:56:30: received status 0 message END_OF_TX
```