# Как вместо dbms_output.put_line вывод записывать в файл на стороне клиента?

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsql-developer

Есть блок на PL/SQL. В нем используется `dbms_output.put_line`. Но вывод оказывается слишком большой (больше буфера).

На что следует заменить `dbms_output.put_line`, чтобы поток шел в файл на стороне клиента, а не в буфер output?

Comment: Если файл на сервере смотрите пакет UTL_FILE

Comment: Да, я его уже заценил, но файл не на сервере, а хотелось бы на свой диск.

Comment: это невозможно, должна быть поддержка со стороны клиента

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для записи в файл локально на стороне клиента необходима ещё одна сессия, которая перенаправит вывод из PL/SQL блока во время его выполнения.

Для наглядного примера, взял без каких либо изменений пользовательский тип [из этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/158792/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b1%d1%8d%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82-%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%80%d1%8b/804467?r=SearchResults&s=3|13.7778#804467).
Добавил функцию, чтобы вывод можно было получить простым запросом:

```
create or replace type notificationRows as table of notification;
/
create or replace function receiveNotification return notificationRows pipelined is
    msg notification; 
begin 
    <<receiveUntilEOF>> loop  
        msg := notification.receive;
        exit receiveUntilEOF when msg.text = 'EOF';
        pipe row (msg);
    end loop receiveUntilEOF; 
    return;
end;
/
```

Для перенаправления вывода запроса в файл можно воспользоваться любым доступным на стороне клиента способом. Например, команда `SPOOL` так же доступна в PL/SQL Developer.
Из SQL*Plus вообще очень просто:

```
$ echo "set arrays 1 pages 0 feedback off timing off 
      select t.text from table (receiveNotification ()) t;" | \
      sqlplus -l -s user/pass@dbsrv/service > file.out
```

И вывод из блока, во время выполнения его на БД сервере:

```
begin
    notification.send ('start output');
    for i in 1..3 loop
        dbms_lock.sleep (1);
        notification.send ('wrote line '||i);
    end loop;    
    notification.send ('EOF');
end;
/
```

будет перенаправлен в файл на машине клиента:

```
$ cat file.out
start output
wrote line 1
wrote line 2
wrote line 3
```